# Turing Machine divisibility by 6

Tags: computer-science, turing-machines

I need to design a TM to check if a binary number can be dividied by 6.
I don't know how to design it.

Thanks

Comment: Questions tend to get more attention when you show what you have tried. Can you design your machine for divisibility by 2? That should be easier.

Comment: A finite automaton suffices...

Comment: Can you find *any* algorithm that finds if a binary number can be divided by 6? (J.E.Pin recommends a finite state automaton, but you could use another kind of algorithm.) If so, can you translate that algorithm to a Turing Machine? Be more specific what your difficulty is.

Comment: The main point was that I was trying to design it all together, instead of dividing the problem. What I've done and seems that it works is to check the divisibility by 2 and, if it's possible, go ahead with the divisibility by 3. That's my solution right now, but I'm gonna try to improve it

Comment: @CaptainSpock: Please add this comment above to the description within your question, so it can be reopened.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment to your question, a finite automaton should do:

- There are $6$ states altogether
- State "$0$" is the initial state
- State "$0$" is also the accept state
- All other states are reject states
- The input should be injected MSB first / LSB last
- Please note that in essence `NextState = (2 x CurrState + InputBit) % 6`

---

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

A number is divisible by 6 if and only if it is divisible by both 2 and 3.

1. Binary number is divisible by 2 iff its last digit is 0.
2. A number base-10 is divisible by 3 iff the sum of its digits is divisible by 3.

Can you finish this?

Comment: This seems like a very roundabout way to program a Turing machine.

Answer (score 0):

To check for divisibility by $3$ first right-shift until the last digit is a $1$. Remove this digit along with another $1$ in the positions $2,8,32,128,\dots$ or two from positions $4,16,64,\dots$, divide by $2$'s again and repeat.
If this can't be done, the number isn't divisible by $3$.